# Android material design: remove hint animation

Tags: android, material-design, autocompletetextview, hint

I am building an app that has some `AutoCompleteTextView`, using amterial design `AppCompat`. I need to remove the hint animation that this component has, when you tap on the field and the hint goes up, in a smooth animation. Is there any way to remove this animation?

My layout:

```
<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/email_login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:theme="@style/AutoCompleteTextViewListasVipHolo" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified" android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/register_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/action_register"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don´t want to lose the auto complete feature.

Comment: Post your layout at least. It will be much easier to help you

Comment: <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                     />

Comment: @erickles Post your full xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove the floating label, then remove the `TextInputLayout` wrapping around your `AutoCompleteTextView`. This will remove the floating label feature.

If you want the floating label, but disable the animation, then with the support design library v23 you can use `textInputLayout.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);` in your code

or `app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"` as a parameter to the `TextInputLayout` in XML.

Comment: I removed the TextInputLayout and work it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It can be done programmatically very easily by doing the steps below.

1. Set textInputLayout's hint to null

```java
textInputLayout.setHint(null);
```

2. Set TextInput**EditText's** hint to your hint text

```java
EditText editText = textInputLayout.getEditText();
editText.setHint("your hint text");
```